# Where can I find styles.xml and themes.xml in the Android source?

Tags: android

I'm referring to the two links [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#PlatformStyles) that are broken: "Android Styles (styles.xml)" and "Android Themes (themes.xml)"

Where can I find the source to these? I know that the Android source code [is cloned to github](https://github.com/android) but I have no idea where to look.

Specifically, I'm wanting the Honeycomb (or Ice Cream Sandwich) version of these so I can see how some of the Holo themes are defined.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure your dev machine has HC/ICS SDK. Then you can find the files on your machine.

For instance, for Android 4.0 those files are placed at `<android-sdk-root-dir>\platforms\android-14\data\res\values` dir.

Comment: Oh nice. I didn't realize the data was already there. This saves the 700mb download from the `git clone`. You win, sir.

Answer (score 6):

Okay, I found them here:

- [themes.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml)
- [styles.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml)

But this repo is out of date and does not have the HC/ICS versions of the files.

So I ended up pulling the Android source myself and found them there:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git
```