# Color Value for Blue under ActionBar in Android ActionBarActivity?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"` and extending ActionBarActivity. Under the action bar is a blue line and I would like to use that same blue color elsewhere in the app to give a consistent look to the app. How do I find out the rgb color value for this bar?

I've read a lot of SO posts about changing the color of this line, but none about using it elsewhere!

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: That's a workaround but why not print screen it and check in an image editing software?

Comment: Thank you... I'm now googling how to take a screenshot on the phone!

Comment: Volume down button and power button pressed simultaneously for about a second. This worked on a Sony Xperia E, but what I read suggests that this should work on most phones > Android 4.0

Comment: Why don't you just look at the Android source for the SDK. It'll be somewhere in either the styles or themes XML files... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407507/where-can-i-find-styles-xml-and-themes-xml-in-the-android-source

Comment: @RafaelCardoso : Using a fixed ARGB8888 value instead of using the Android themes/styles is going to hard-code that blue value regardless of how themes may change in the future. Your suggestion isn't just a workaround, it's an immutable hack.

Comment: I agree, Squonk. That is why I said, it is a workaround, it will probably meet his requirements but it is far from being the best solution

Comment: From the SDK (sdk\platforms\android-19\data\res\values\colors.xml) I have found that the color name is holo_blue_light. How do I use this in setColorFilter? I tried Color.holo_blue_light but got an error "...cannot be resolved or is not a field" Thanks.

Comment: @Squonk A bit of googling suggested this should work... `int blue = getResources().getColor(R.color.holo_blue_light);` but it still gives the error "holo_blue_light cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is what I think is the correct answer.

1. I took a screenshot with volume down button and power button pressed simultaneously for about a second. (Sony Xperia E and should work on other phones > Android 4.0)
2. Transfered photo to PC and used Instant Eyedropper (http://instant-eyedropper.com/) to get the color value.
3. The blue line underneath the action bar with `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"`is 0xFF33B5E5 (aRGB in hex)
4. I then searched the color values found in sdk\platforms\android-19\data\res\values\colors.xml and found that color value had the name "holo_blue_light".
5. I then used the following line of code to use that color in the app: `int light_blue = getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_light);`

Thanks to Rafael and Squonk whose comments guided me to what I hope is the correct conclusion!

Andrew

Comment: Rafael didn't point you in the right direction. What you've effectively done is arrive at a fixed ARGB8888 value which may or may not be correct depending on different device capabilities. Just because it looks that way for your screenshot doesn't mean it will for everyones screen. Worse than that - if you hard-code that value and a Theme actually uses Lime Green (for example), your app will look odd as it will have the blue instead of green. You want consistency - that's what styles and themes are for - I posted a link which will help you find the color alias - use that for consistency.

Comment: So `Theme.AppCompat` might change in the future? I assumed that by specifying that theme I was guaranteeing those colors would be used. Am I wrong?

Comment: There's no telling what may happen in the future. The default styles/themes of Android have changed over various versions. At one point (HoneyComb I believe) the default was to use a white background and black text. We have themes such as Holo Dark, Holo Light, Holo Light with Dark Action Bar etc. The whole point of using the XML resource files is they have fixed names for resources - one theme might define "some_color" as bright red whereas another defines it as pale blue. To achieve consistency, use resource names and not hard-coded values. Either that or define your own theme totally.

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking that Theme.AppCompat is a theme like Holo Dark and therefore has fixed colours which can be relied upon to be the same in the future?